# How do I repeat page header on every page except the first page of a report?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a client report (.rdlc) that I am editing in Visual Studio.  I need a way to display an empty page header on every page, except the first page of the report.

The reason for this is because the client has paper with their logo that needs space at the top to display on subsequent pages.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly, this might help you.

On the report, right-click on the page header and select the option `Header Properties...`

[image: Header Properties]

On *Page Header Properties*, uncheck the option **Print on first page**. Now the page header will not appear on the first page of the report.

[image: Uncheck print on first page]

Answer (score 2):

Create an empty textbox that is big enough to hold the logo.

Then, for the `Hidden` property of that textbox, use the expression:

```
=IIf(Globals!PageNumber=1,false,true)
```

That will hide the textbox on the first page but show it on all others.

Comment: Mainly, what I need is a way to add additional whitespace either via the header or body on all pages other than the first page.  In short, I guess what I need is a way to resize the body dynamically.

Comment: Yes, that's what this solution should give you. Just make the textbox big enough to hold the logo and this solution should make the whitespace appear on every page but the first.